# Realm Queries in React Native: What is the best practice for where to locate your queries?

Tags: react-native, realm

In React Native, using Realm, what is the best practice for where to perform your queries? Meaning, if you require data for the initial state, should your queries be done within ComponentWillMount? Or should you simply update state after ComponentDidMount? Or should queries ALWAYS be located within render()? Or should you perform the query prior to navigation to the scene and pass the results as props?

Basically looking for some best practices on where you should, and should not, perform Realm Queries based on when your app may need the data.

Hope this isn't too generic, doesn't seem to be a lot of resources for Realm/React Native, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should perform your queries on your `constructor` and then change state in `ComponentDidMount` and use `ActivityIndicator` or some kind of feedback 
to let the user know that you are fetching some data.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
    });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(dataSource), // Bad
      items: realm.objects('Item').sorted('name'),
    };
    this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.items),
    });
  }
```

Example from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36610715/1216601

Comment: Ahh, I see from the example you linked... you actually perform the query in the constructor, then use the results to populate the initial state. Am I translating that right?

Comment: Exactly, if you want to refresh the `ListView` data you can use another function to query and then update `this.state` to render the results.